# Amazon SNS rate limiting on HTTPS endpoint

Tags: amazon-sns

I have a issue with the rate that Amazon SNS calls our HTTPS endpoint. Our server can't handle that much calls at once and crashes eventually.

**The situation**

We are sending newsletters with Amazon SES (Simple Email Service). The notifications about bounces / complaints / delivery are send to a SNS topic (all the same).

We are sending the newsletter with a rate of 2000 e-mail per minute. This also means that we receive the SNS topics with a rate of 2000 per minute. The sending of newsletters and receiving of the SNS topics are all handled by the same server.

The server is already busy by sending those newsletters, and in the meantime it must also handle the SNS topics and that is to much.

So I actually want to limit the rate of the SNS topics, so that they are send and a rate of eg 500 per minute. I can't find something like that in the policy.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an SQS queue and subscribe it to the SNS topic? Then, your service can process messages from queue later/when it is possible.

Comment: I see that I can subscribe the SNS topic to a SQS queue. I am not familiar with all Amazon services, so I have to delve into this.

Comment: np, here's a tutorial that can be a starting point https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html